# Constructor not defined error - error after setting date fields as null during object creation

Tags: apex, error, date, wrapper-class, constructor

I have created a wrapper class to create an Object and send it as a request to a third party system. It was working well. But after I added a two new arguments of the Datatype Date, I am getting the below error.

```
Constructor not defined: [SFDC_DataObject.CustomerAccountObject].<Constructor>(Id, String, Id, String, Id, String, Integer, NULL, String, String, Id, String, NULL, String, String, String, String)
```

The request that I am creating and sending is as below.

```
SFDC_DataObject.CustomerAccountObject cusAccObj = new SFDC_DataObject.CustomerAccountObject(o.AccountId, o.Customer_Name__c, o.Agency_Name__r.Id,o.Agency_Name_OB__c, o.Opportunity.OwnerId, o.Opportunity.Owner.FederationIdentifier, PrimarySalesSplitPercent, null, secSOSalesforceId.get(o.OpportunityId), secSOSalesforceEmail.get(o.OpportunityId), o.Opportunity.Customer_Success_Manage__r.Id, o.Opportunity.Customer_Success_Manage__r.FederationIdentifier, null, o.Billing_Email__c, o.Billing_Phone__c, o.Bill_To_Name__c, o.Billing_Notes__c);
```

My wrapper class for the same object is as below.

```
public class CustomerAccountObject {
        public String  sfCustomerId;
        public String  customerName;
        public String  sfAgencyId;
        public String  agencyName;
        public String  sfPrimarySalesOwnerId;
        public String  primarySalesOwnerEmail;
        public Integer primarySalesOwnerPercentage;
        public Date    primarySalesOwnerEffectiveFrom;
        public String  sfSecondarySalesOwnerId;
        public String  secondarySalesOwnerEmail;
        public Date    secondarySalesOwnerEffectiveFrom;
        public String  sfAccountManagerId;
        public String  accountManagerEmail;
        public String  billingEmail;
        public String  billingPhone;
        public String  billingName;
        public String  billingNotes;

        public CustomerAccountObject() {}

        public CustomerAccountObject(String sfCustomerId, String customerName, String sfAgencyId, String agencyName, String sfPrimarySalesOwnerId, String primarySalesOwnerEmail, Integer primarySalesOwnerPercentage, Date primarySalesOwnerEffectiveFrom, String sfSecondarySalesOwnerId, String secondarySalesOwnerEmail, Date secondarySalesOwnerEffectiveFrom, String sfAccountManagerId, String accountManagerEmail, String billingEmail, String billingPhone, String billingName, String billingNotes) {
            this.sfCustomerId                     = sfCustomerId;
            this.customerName                     = customerName;
            this.sfAgencyId                       = sfAgencyId;
            this.agencyName                       = agencyName;
            this.sfPrimarySalesOwnerId            = sfPrimarySalesOwnerId;
            this.primarySalesOwnerEmail           = primarySalesOwnerEmail;
            this.primarySalesOwnerPercentage      = primarySalesOwnerPercentage;
            this.primarySalesOwnerEffectiveFrom   = primarySalesOwnerEffectiveFrom;
            this.sfSecondarySalesOwnerId          = sfSecondarySalesOwnerId;
            this.secondarySalesOwnerEmail         = secondarySalesOwnerEmail;
            this.secondarySalesOwnerEffectiveFrom = secondarySalesOwnerEffectiveFrom;
            this.sfAccountManagerId               = sfAccountManagerId;
            this.accountManagerEmail              = accountManagerEmail;
            this.billingEmail                     = billingEmail;
            this.billingPhone                     = billingPhone;
            this.billingName                      = billingName;
            this.billingNotes                     = billingNotes;
        }
    }
```

I began getting the error after I added the null for the Date arguments I.e primarySalesOwnerEffectiveFrom and **secondarySalesOwnerEffectiveFrom** during the Object creation.

Can anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There error message is quite clear, if you compare the error message's parameter with your constructor's, it gives a clue.

```
|   Actual      |   Expected in constructor                 |                   |
|   ---         |   ---                                     |   ---             |
|   Id          |   String sfCustomerId                     |                   |
|   String      |   String customerName                     |                   |
|   Id          |   String sfAgencyId                       |                   |
|   String      |   String agencyName                       |                   |
|   Id          |   String sfPrimarySalesOwnerId            |                   |
|   String      |   String primarySalesOwnerEmail           |                   |
|   Integer     |   Integer primarySalesOwnerPercentage     |                   |
|   NULL        |   Date primarySalesOwnerEffectiveFrom     |                   |
|   String      |   String sfSecondarySalesOwnerId          |                   |
|   String      |   String secondarySalesOwnerEmail         |                   |
|   Id          |   Date secondarySalesOwnerEffectiveFrom   |   Problem is here |
|   String      |   String sfAccountManagerId               |                   |
|   NULL        |   String accountManagerEmail              |                   |
|   String      |   String billingEmail                     |                   |
|   String      |   String billingPhone                     |                   |
|   String      |   String billingName                      |                   |
|   String      |   String billingNotes                     |                   |
```

Comment: Hi @Raul *Facepalm* I hadn't observed that. Thank you for pointing out. It works now.

Comment: No worries, happens with everyone. cheers :)